# Return an Integer between 1 and 52, based on a given Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a client that's giving me data sets that are broken down into quarters, periods (a block of four weeks in a quarter), and weeks. I'm writing a quick reference algorithm to return the quarter, period, week given a date and year and vise versa.

Their data is always broken down into 52 weeks, where week 1 always contains Jan 1st and starts with the Monday before or at Jan 1st. This is how they handle the 365 / 7 = 52.142857 conundrum.

So, is there a gem or built in function (cweek returns 1-53), that would give me a week number based on the premise that week 1 always contains Jan 1st or do I need to design something additional?

Comment: In what universe week 1 does contain Jan 1? What’s wrong with `cweek`?

Comment: I've attempted all of the date functions in the Date package, including cweek. So, using cweek on `Date.new(2016,1,1).cweek` returns 53. Which is not what I need. As far as universe, I can't help you there.

Comment: @mudasobwa E.g. North America, some Asian countries (incl. China), South Africa and most of Latin America commonly use a week numbering scheme where week 1 is indeed the one containing January 1. More common throughout the world however are week numbers according to ISO 8601 where the first week is the one containing January 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Way 1. [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime)

```
Date.new(2016,1,1).strftime("%U").to_i + 1 # week starts with Sunday
Date.new(2016,1,1).strftime("%W").to_i + 1 # week starts with Monday
```

#### Way 2. [Date#cweek](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-cweek)

```
Date.new(2016,1,1).cweek % 53 + 1 # week starts with Monday
```

Comment: "Way 2" Is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Comment: `p Date.new(2016,12,19).strftime("%W")   #Returns "51"`
`p Date.new(2016,12,19).cweek            #Returns 51`
`p Date.new(2016,12,19).cweek % 53 + 1   #Returns 52`
Since 12/19/2016 is the last Monday of their 2016 reporting cycle, the week should be 52.
`p Date.new(2015,12,28).strftime("%W")   #Returns "52"`
`p Date.new(2015,12,28).cweek            #Returns 53`
`p Date.new(2015,12,28).cweek % 53 + 1   #Returns 1`
Since 12/28/2015 is the first Monday of their 2016 reporting cycle, the week returned for that should be 1.